# Producing a list of links while reading Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an array in my JavaScript with `Person{name, address}` object. Now I would like to display it  on my MVC view as a list of links such that Name is linked and address is not.

A grid, a table, or anything would be fine to start with. I just need some suggestions. Are there any JQuery plug-ins that I can use? Or something that I can do with Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might be helpful

[**Telerik Extensions for MVC DEMOS**](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)

[**KENDO UI**](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html)